# Laravel Installing Error: "touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied"

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, composer-php, laravel-5.1

I've used and installed laravel for many times but today when I tried to install laravel for my new project I got the following error:

```
  - Installing symfony/finder (v2.7.6)
Downloading: 100%         

- Installing symfony/dom-crawler (v2.7.6)

[ErrorException]                          
 touch(): Utime failed: Permission denied
```

I've tried my best to find the reason but I'm unable to detect what's wrong.

As it's happening for the first time and never happened before. Every thing was OK before installing "Vagrant", "Homestead" (which was not downloaded completely) and "redis". Any way This is where I've struck for first time and still couldn't recover. Can any one help me in this regard?

Comment: Try running `composer clearcache` are retrying.

Comment: OMG! It's really worked! what was happening behind that? Can you please elaborate????

Comment: That particular package was probably cached by composer and it tried to fetch it from the cache, but the permissions might have been wrong for it so the error was triggered. By clearing the cache, the package needed to be downloaded again when installing, thus avoiding the permission problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
sudo php composer clear-cache
```

this  worked for me

Comment: Isn't that     `sudo composer clear-cache` or     `sudo php composer.phar clear-cache` ?

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions above worked for me as I was still getting permissions issues.

To fix, I had to run `composer install` while ssh'd into the virtual machine.